# Microsoft Graph API for listing channel messages and post channel throws bad request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are using list channel messages beta api with $top=1 to get the most recent message
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${team_id}/channels/${channel}/messages?$top=1

And for posting the messaging https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${team_id}/channels/${channel}/messages API used with the following request body

`{
    subject: 'Head Post',
    body: {
        contentType: 'html',
        content: '<b><i>Hi</i></b> Introduce yourself.'
    }
}`

.
Tenant global admin accesstoken is provided as bearer token.

Sometimes it gives the following error and it is not informative.

`{
    error: {
        code: 'BadRequest',
        message: 'Bad Request',
        innerError: {
            'request-id': 'bbd96990-bd80-4023-b7a6-925319dc79ef',
            date: '2020-05-12T19:19:11'
        }
    }
}`

*error.response.headers*

`{
    'cache-control': 'private',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'request-id': 'bbd96990-bd80-4023-b7a6-925319dc79ef',
    'client-request-id': 'bbd96990-bd80-4023-b7a6-925319dc79ef',
    'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_22"}}',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
    date: 'Tue, 12 May 2020 19:19:11 GMT',
    connection: 'close',
    'content-length': '207'
}`

Can anyone explain what causes the error and how to resolve that ?

Comment: Do you get this issue intermittently ?

Comment: I have tried the the given request body in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview) and it works fine for me.

Comment: Yes  this issue intermittently. Particularly for this kind of message <b><i>Hi</i></b> Introduce yourself.
It seems send channel message is successful even with that error. Is that possible ?

Comment: We are discussing with internal team on this. will update you shortly.

Comment: Can you please share the request Id, the one you have shared in the post  is for fetch request.

Comment: Our Team confirms that message  is posted to the channel . But response is coming as BadRequest .                                                                                                             Request Id while posting the message                                                                                
 `{
 error: {
  code: 'BadRequest',
  message: 'Bad Request',
  innerError: {
   'request-id': 'f128992a-d899-4ae3-bd7a-a4ff07bb31ef',
   date: '2020-05-25T06:56:47'
   }
  }
}`

Comment: Here is the response Headers. `=-=- error.response.headers =-=-
{
 'cache-control': 'private',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 'request-id': 'f128992a-d899-4ae3-bd7a-a4ff07bb31ef',
 'client-request-id': 'f128992a-d899-4ae3-bd7a-a4ff07bb31ef',
 'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_23"}}',
 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
 date: 'Mon, 25 May 2020 06:56:47 GMT',
 connection: 'close',
 'content-length': '207'
}`

Comment: The channel id you are passing does not belong to that team. So there is a groupID and channelId mismatch. Can you please verify it one.